# jQuery css to multiple elements?

Tags: jquery, foreach

I need to apply this script to work the same way for two other divs:
This works well, but how can I make it do the same thing for two other elements without rewriting the entire thing for each?

```
$(".survey_option li > a").each().live('click', function (event) {
    // First disable the normal link click
    event.preventDefault();

    // Remove all list and links active class.
    $('.so_1 .active').toggleClass("active");
    // Grab the link clicks ID
    var id = this.id;

    // The id will now be something like "link1"
    // Now we need to replace link with option (this is the ID's of the checkbox)
    var newselect = id.replace('partc', 'optionc');

    // Make newselect the option selected.
    $('#'+newselect).attr('checked', true);

    // Now add active state to the link and list item
    $(this).addClass("active").parent().addClass("active");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: which elements are the `<div>` elements: `.so_1 .active` and `.so_2 .active`?

Comment: Oops!  Thos are the other columns...I'll edit that.

Comment: I'm still not clear on which elements are the `<div>` elements. Would you mind adding the tag names to the selectors to make it clearer what element types you are targeting in each selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cause it to affect multiple elements by changing your selector:

```
$(".element_1, .element_2, .randomElement, #someOtherThing");
```

Note also that you don't need to call `$.each()` before adding your `$.live()` call. `$.live()` will be applied to all of the matched elements, doing its own internal `$.each()` logic.

```
$(".elem1, .elem2 > a, #someThing").live("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).text()); // works on all elements in the selector
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Ariel :) I saw some room for more details, and pounced on it ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about wrapping your function in another function, like so...

```
function modMyDiv(selectorClass) {
    $("." + selectorClass + " li > a").each().live('click', function (event) {
        // First disable the normal link click
        event.preventDefault();

        // Remove all list and links active class.
        $('.so_1 .active').removeClass("active");
        $('.so_2 .active').removeClass("active");       
        // Grab the link clicks ID
        var id = this.id;

        // The id will now be something like "link1"
        // Now we need to replace link with option (this is the ID's of the checkbox)
        var newselect = id.replace('partc', 'optionc');

        // Make newselect the option selected.
        $('#'+newselect).attr('checked', true);

        // Now add active state to the link and list item
        $(this).addClass("active").parent().addClass("active");

        return false;
    });
}
```

Then

```
modMyDiv('survey_option');
modMyDiv('other_class');
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to call the `.each()` method, `.live()` will bind itself to all elements that your selector matches. So, all you need to do is match all the elements you want using selectors:

```
$(".survey_option li > a, #secondElement, #thirdElement > p").live('click', function (event) {
    // do it all...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make it a jQuery function for ease of calling...

```
$.fn.myFunct = function() {
    $(this).each()...
}
```

Then call it on anything you like:

```
$("#this, .that, otherstuff").myFunct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap it as an object and extend it to other selectors.